# Python if/then Statement in Field Calculator to return 0 or 1 based on numbers divisible by 28?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I don't use python all the time.

In a point feature class, I'm trying to populate an ID field with 1's and 0's based on whether the FID is divisible by 28.

I've started the following code but can't get it to execute:

[image]

```
def myCalc(FID,ID):
  if FID % 28 == 0:
    return 1
  else:
    return 0
```

Comment: Do you need "ID" as an input in your function? Or are you trying to return 1 and 0 to ID? Also the screen shot shows that VBA is selected. Have you tried it with Python selected?

Comment: make sure you are setting the parser to Python.  In the screenshot you have it a VB

Comment: I'm trying to return 0 and 1 to ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for completeness, to summarise what was said in the comments:

You don't need "ID" as an input parameter of your function.

```
def myCalc(FID):
  if FID % 28 == 0:
    return 1
  else:
    return 0
```

So, when you call the function, all you need is:

```
myCalc(!FID!)
```

Also, ensure the parser is set to Python.